# java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, socks

i try to create SSLSocket with socket but i get this exception

```
 SocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Socket underlying = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr));
underlying.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(underlying,proxyHost,proxyPort,true);
```

Exception:
   java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server

Thank you for your help

Comment: please make sure that you are pointing to the correct proxy address. A very common error is you are giving normal port whereas you have to give https port of the proxy server

Comment: @FreakyThommi HTTPS has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured your application to use a SOCKS proxy but the entity at the host:port you specified as the `proxyAddr` isn't a SOCKS server.

Comment: as you say the problem is i should not use proxyHost/proxyPort to create SSLSocket,but i how to use SOCKS server to create SSLSocket.
Thanks

Comment: @Michaelwu That's not what I said at all. `proxyHost/proxyPort` are for HTTP proxies, not SOCKS proxies. You don't *have* a SOCKS server, or at least not at the IP:port you specified. Either you should not use `Proxy.Type.SOCKS` at all, or you should specify the correct proxy address.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

> 1) Open Tools -> Internet Options in Internet Explorer (or alternatively, Control Panel Network Settings in Windows 7)
>
> 2) Open Connections tab
>
> 3) Click on LAN settings
>
> 4) If "Use a proxy server" is enabled, click Advanced and disable "Use the same proxy server for all protocols"

Comment: This just controls what Internet Explorer does. It has nothing to do with Java. The OP's code is *explicity* use a SOCKS proxy, or trying to. Not relying on any Control Panel setting.

Comment: I solve my problem with Malformed reply from SOCKS server using this, if lan settings use socks proxy on System, Java don't subscribe :/

Comment: You fixed it by setting this in the control panel and then removing the SOCKS proxy from your Java code. Java doesn't take any notice of the Control Panel and certainly not of any Internet Explorer options.